# Display data in jtextfield one by one not all at a time

Tags: java, swing, textfield

Below is the code. It read from com port and display data in the text field created by the netbeans gui. This code runs. It actually merge 5 com data and display at once in the end.

I want to display single data in the gui one by one. Not all 5 data together at the end of the program. Actually I want the gui will run, Then the textfield filled with 5 data read from com port.

```
package learn;

import jssc.SerialPort;
import jssc.SerialPortException;

public class gui extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form gui
 */
public gui() {
    initComponents();
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
        comport();
}

private void comport() {
    SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3");
    int count = 1;
    try {
        serialPort.openPort(); //Open serial port
        serialPort.setParams(9600, 8, 1, 0);//Set params.
        byte[] buffer = serialPort.readBytes(32);//Read 10 bytes from serial port
        final String readed = new String(buffer);
        //  System.out.println("««Readed from COM"  + ": " + readed);

        jTextArea1.append(readed+ "\n" );
        serialPort.closePort();//Close serial port   
    } catch (SerialPortException ex) {
       System.out.println(ex);
    }
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
    jTextArea1.setRows(5);
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(27, 27, 27)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 241, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(132, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(22, 22, 22)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 126, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(152, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new gui().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
// End of variables declaration                   

}
```

Comment: Do this reading and appending stuff in a separate thread

Comment: Do you think it will work? I need to display GUI first. Then appending com data on textfield. With this current code comport () method excute first then it display the data all together.

Comment: May be you must use String buffer to concatenate every readed String with new line operator, and the to append this to jTextArea1? I have the impresion that String readed is generated as a long String, with all values together, or you may split this string based on some specific character.

Answer (score 0):

```
package learn;

import jssc.SerialPort;
import jssc.SerialPortException;

public class GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Runnable{

    /**
     * Creates new form GUI
     */

    Thread thread;
    public GUI() {
        initComponents();
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new GUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   

    @Override
    public void run() {
      for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
    comport();
    }
    private void comport(){

      SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3");

      int count = 1;


  //  while (count < 11) {
     try {

        serialPort.openPort();//Open serial port
        serialPort.setParams(9600, 8, 1, 0);//Set params.
        byte[] buffer = serialPort.readBytes(32);//Read 10 bytes from serial port
        final String readed = new String(buffer);
      //  System.out.println("≪≪Readed from COM"  + ": " + readed);

        jTextArea1.append(readed+ "\n" );
        serialPort.closePort();//Close serial port

    }
    catch (SerialPortException ex) {
       System.out.println(ex);
    }
   //count++;
   // }

}
}
```

Try something like this, I haven't made much changes, just created a Thread.

Comment: Giving error no suitable constructor found for Thread.Any solution for this.

Comment: I create the thread. Now problem is gui is running. But no data in the GUI. Override run function is not going.

Comment: You Started the thread and run is not working?
Try printing something in run method !